# Using mediainfo/MOVmediaedit to mimic GoPro video format

Tags: video, mp4, h.264, media-info, gopro

GoPro has cool "quick edit" video editor, called Quik Desktop. It'll only import videos generated with GP's own cameras. As long as I use GP's camera's Quik is fabulous.

However, sometimes I want to include a clip or two from other video sources (ie: mobile phone shot).

GP cameras save in MP4, h264, which I can transcode into. I can also match resolution, framerate. But it seems like it's not enough. Are there scripts, or easy-to-use bindings into mediainfo to "clone" the metadata? I can work most popular Linux/unix scripting languages.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is something only the product's tech support can answer. They can use any of the format's features that doesn't noticeably affect playback to secretly mark a file. You signed up for this by using software that is [tied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tying_(commerce)) to a product. Below is what they let on.

If you give a sample of a valid file, we might be able to see anything unusual about it.

Here's all the GoPro's support says:

https://gopro.com/help/articles/Question_Answer/What-Video-Format-do-GoPro-Cameras-Record-in

> Video files are recorded using the h.264 codec and the MP4 file type,
>   the exception being some resolution/frame rate combinations on the
>   HERO6 Black. With the HERO6 Black, HEVC (h.265) is utilized for
>   applicable modes. For more information, see: HEVC Explained.

https://gopro.com/help/articles/Question_Answer/What-Type-of-Media-Files-Can-I-Add-to-a-GoPro-Studio-Project

> **Step 1: View and Trim**
>
> The following formats can be imported into “Step 1: View & Trim” and
>   converted into GoPro CineForm files for use in “Step 2: Edit”. You can
>   use GoPro App for Desktop to open these files in Step 1 as well.
>
> MP4 video files from the original HD Hero Original, HD Hero 2, HERO3,
>   HERO3+, HERO and HERO4 cameras. JPG files from GoPro HD Hero, Hero 2
>   and Hero 3 cameras (.jpgs from other sources may work, but have not
>   been tested nor are they officially supported)
>
> **Step 2: Edit**
>
> Step 2: Edit can import the following file formats:
>
> Video formats: GoPro CineForm AVI or MOV files (MOV only on Mac)
>
> Audio formats: MP3, WAV, AIFF, M4A and CAF

Comment: Thanks for looking those things up. The first doc, I had - confirms MP4/h.264. Second doc is about a different bit of software.

I _know_ this is not supported. I'm hoping to dress my files up, in Trojan horse fashion, by mimicking their format and metadata. Maybe it works, maybe it doesn't. Just need some help locating practical tooling to do this...

Comment: @MartinLanghoff As I said, theoretically, it can be anything. The simplest though is some custom field in metadata. https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo that you already mentioned will likely show those. What else do you expect to hear?